# A basic estimate of exponential sums

Tags: nt.number-theory, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, analytic-number-theory, fourier-analysis, exponential-sums

Demeter in his book "Fourier Restriction, Decoupling, and Applications" (P287) used the following estimate:

\begin{equation}
\sup_{0\leq n\leq q}\bigg|\sum_{m=0}^n e^{2\pi i\frac{a}{q}m^2}\bigg|\leq Cq^{\frac{1}{2}},
\end{equation}
where $a,q\in \mathbb{N}_+$ satisfy $(a,q)=1$ and $2\nmid q$.

The case $n=q$ can be calculated directly to be $q^{\frac{1}{2}}$. For general $n$, the usual Weyl's method will lead to an extra term $\log n$. Could you please explain how to get this estimate?

Comment: Is [this](http://new.math.uiuc.edu/oldnew/math595/2015/jli135/Incomplete%20gauss%20sums.pdf) what you want?

Comment: This helps a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

The main idea is to apply Poisson summation formula. It allows to replace $a/q$ by $\lfloor q/a\rfloor$ and then repeat the procedure using continued fraction expansion of $a/q$. This idea belongs to [Hardy and Littlewood](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/acta-mathematica/volume-37/issue-none/Some-problems-of-diophantine-approximation--Part-II-The-trigonometrical/10.1007/BF02401834.full), but afterwards it was rediscovered many times. You can find references and explicite estimates in the article [On Incomplete Gaussian Sums](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1134/S008154381506005X.pdf) by
M. A. Korolev.

Comment: Thank you! Does there exist a relatively simple proof? The sharp constant is not important to me.

Comment: @DapaoZhang Unfortunately I don't know where you can find the simple proof.  It is always necessary to deal with the error term in Poisson summation formula.